# Hoppscotch APIs

Tags: postman, hoppscotch

I am looking out to see if any open apis are there to build hoppscotch Collection from the existing collection JSON.

I need to migrate the postman collection to Hoppscotch collection.
Hoppscotch is currently giving the option to upload postman collection JSON but I need an API to do the same.